# Infinitive forms

Tags: infinitives

Can you kindly help me in replacing these sentences using infinitive forms?

> 1) The principal knows that these students use alcohol and drugs.
>
> 2) In this school the administrators mandated drug testing. It was
>   necessary.

Comment: "The school administrators mandated drug testing to deter drug use."or you can say "The school administrators mandated drug testing to keep their students from abusing drugs"

Comment: Replacing both sentences with only one? Could you illustrate by giving an example of a transformation?

Comment: Why would you want to use an infinitive in these sentences? Is this a question in an English test?

Comment: @Mia I was thinking the same thing: the sentences appear to be connected. “In this school, the administration mandated drug testing to stop the students from using alcohol and drugs.”

Comment: @user2684291. Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to rewrite the above sentences using an infinitive :

1.The school administrators mandated drug testing to deter drug use.

2.The school administrators mandated drug testing to keep their students from abusing drugs.

3.The fact that most students may be using drugs causes the school administrators to drug test the students.

4.The fact that most students may be using drugs led the school administrators to implement / to consider implementing a drug testing policy.

5.The school administrators mandated drug testing to prevent students from using alcohol and drugs.